# KML to geoJSON - how to include styles?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml, geojson

We have been using KML to allow clients to upload Layers to a Google Maps based App.  We are trying to replace KML with geoJSON, and all is fine with the exception of styles.

The style definitions in the KML files do not get included in the conveted geoJSON file (we have used a number of converters, but the one we are working with mainly is http://converter.mygeodata.eu/)

As you can see in the KML below, there is a style block there (purple box), but this just gets excluded from any generated geoJSON.

Does anyone know of a converter, or way of converting KML to geoJSON, that retains the style?

Thanks

Jason

[image]

Comment: This seems to be fairly simple and handy tool: http://ogre.adc4gis.com/.

Comment: Thanks KayAnn, we have used that one, but it doesn't convert the <style> to the geoJSON either.  Or am I missing something?  Is there a way to have the style included using ogre.adc4gis.com?

Comment: Actually I tried a few kmls too but none of them had style properties in them in general. There are few other ways to work with GeoJSON styles but for that you would have to define style properties in your code after loading the JSON.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the end, I found that *toGeoJson* (http://mapbox.github.io/togeojson/) actually does convert the KML `<style>` node contents into the resulting geoJSON.
All the online tools seem to use *ogr2ogr* on the server side, which ignores the `<style>` as it isn't semantic, but toGeoJson has a go at it and so far does a good job.

I could then just access those properties, after the geoJSON was loaded, to apply the styles.

Comment: Very interesting site! Finally I found a converter that keeps my data :) thanks [@Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1025635/jason)